# VIM, Python: how do you use range objects generated by vim.current.range

Tags: python, vim

```
function! Cut()
python3 << EOF
import vim
cw = vim.current.window
pos = cw.cursor

cr = vim.current.range
x = cr.end - cr.start

vim.command('y')
vim.command(':normal! gv')

print(cr)
print(cr.start)
print(x)

while x:
    vim.command('d')
    x -= 1
EOF
endfunction



I get:
<range ... (10:10)>
9
0
<range ... (11:11)>
10
0
so on..
```

Why am i getting multiple print calls - 1 call per line selected?Shouldn't the range object give you the range of lines selected - it's not doing this, instead it's iterating my lines and setting start=current_line_number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to handle `range` by yourself in your function, you should add `range` argument when you declare/define your function. `:h function-range-example`, then you can in your function get the range information by`a:firstline and a:lastline`. For example:

```
function Foo() range
    let start = a:firstline
...
endfunction
```

In this way, you pass the range once to your function. However if you do, as what you did:

```
function Foo()
    echo "foo"
endfunction
```

then do a `1,10call Foo()` , you will see that 10 `foo` would be printed(echoed). And yes, for each line, your function was invoked.

It is the basic rule, no matter you implement in python or vimscript.

Comment: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/if_pyth.html The range object attributes are:
 r.start  Index of first line into the buffer
 r.end  Index of last line into the buffer

Comment: @Vek.M1234 what I meant is, the problem is on the vim `func Cut()` not in your python codes. You need `func Cut() range` have you read the help doc mentioned in my answer?

Comment: yes, i did read that and I did try: func Cut() range. Within the body, i then tried to access a:firstline from python and it works but it's horribly clumsy. Can't i use the range object that Python provides vs using start = int(vim.eval('a:firstline'))

Comment: function! Cut() range blah blah then cr = vim.current.range start = cr.start stop = cr.stop x = stop - start doesn't work

Comment: @Vek.M1234 in python read the `a:first/lastline` to do your work. the `range` argument let you handle the range on your own, instead of the default way: "for each line in the range, call your function"